# Как выровнить текст по правому краю в Latex, чтобы начала строк совпадали?

Tags: вёрстка, latex, tex

Я использую команду `\begin{flushright}...\end{flushright}` в Latex, но строки в таком случае просто прижимаются вправо и их начала не совпадают.

Как сделать так, чтобы текст был вот так прижат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/207364/ , первый блок кода. flushright — это сдвинуть вправо. только внутри этого окружения должны быть не строки, как у вас, а другое окружение. т.е., вправо должно быть сдвинуто вложенное окружение (с указанной шириной). а вот строки внутри этого вложенного окружения уже никуда сдвигать не требуется — к ним будет применено стандартное выравнивание по левому краю.

Answer (score 3):

Вот такое сработает и для *TeX*, и для *LaTeX*:

```tex
\vbox{%
\hfill%
\vbox{%
\hbox{по дисциплине «Анализ алгоритмов»}%
\hbox{по лабораторной работе №1}%
\hbox{по теме «Расстояние Левенштейна»}%
}%
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Можно выполнить тоже самое, через:

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
по дисциплине «Анализ алгоритмов»\\
по лабораторной работе №1\\
по теме «Расстояние Левенштейна»\\
\end{minipage}
\end{flushright}
```